# How to save all images of a site whilst browsing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, wget

In developer tools in Chrome, I go to: Sources > mysite.com > images

I can preview images, expand the folder where necessary etc.

My question is how can I save all these images in the same folder structure from browsing the site?

I'm not looking for a mirror with something like httrack or wget, I just want the files downloaded, as-and-when I browse different pages

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it will helpful but you can give a simple try by going to web page from chrome and then hit ctrl + s and select option Webpage,Complete for save as type. A html file and folder will be created containing all images from the site ( folder will also contain other files apart from images; sort of a drawback of this method )

Answer (score 4):

Within Chrome Dev Tools, you can only download a single image resource at a time.

To do this in bulk while browsing, you'll need to enable an extension like [Download All Images](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-all-images/ifipmflagepipjokmbdecpmjbibjnakm?hl=en).